# How to generate self-signed certificate and save encryption key inside

Tags: .net-core, encryption, certificate

i am currently trying to generate a self-signed certificate using the powershell, and i can do that already, but the thing is, i am trying as well to save inside the certificate, a string.
How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this. Do you want to store *an encryption key* in a certificate? And what does that have to do with storing a (textual) string?

Comment: i have found a way, what i need to do is, to encrypt data, i will use the certificate in .pfx format, and to decrypt the data, i shall use the private key from the certificate
here is a way to generate a self-signed certificate in .net
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide

Comment: Glad you did, however, your question doesn't indicate at all that you'd need a PFX file or that this could be a solution.

Comment: by what i looked for, if its .pfx file doesn't matter, my case in specific i was using that
But i am going to post a more detailed answer